# What does the ":" do in the interpolated string in C#, for this string $"{1:5d}"?

Tags: c#, string, formatting

```
using System;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine ($"{1:5d}");
   }
}
// The example displays the following output:
// 5d
```

What does the "**:**" do in the interpolated string?
I know if I write,

```
$"{1:d5}"
```

I will get,

```
00001
```

but with this I'm not getting an error/warning means it has to mean something that I don't know.

FYI, I'm on C#7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is separator for [format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated#structure-of-an-interpolated-string). It allows you to specfy [formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#format-string-component) relevant to the type of value on the left. In first case it tries to apply [custom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) format, but since there is no placeholder for actual value - you get only the "value" of the format (try something like `Console.WriteLine ($"{1:00000SomeStringAppended}");` for example, "5d" has the same meaning as "SomeStringAppended" in my example). The second one - `d5` is a standart [decimal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings#standard-format-specifiers) format specifier, so you get corresponding output containing formatted value.

Comment: Yeah, I know the format part. What I want to ask is what does $"{1:5d}}" do, so that it returns 5d. it is an in correct format specifier, so why/how does it work?

Comment: @HitarthDoctor please check the custom format link in the answer. It is a valid custom format (you can put there anything and everything except format specifiers would go in output as is - in your case you have just "5d" string)

Comment: @HitarthDoctor was glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

The following two line would be give the same results - 00001.

```
var i = $"{1:d5}";
var j = string.Format("{0:d5}", 1);
```

A colon : in curly brackets is string formatting.
You can read more about string formatting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation#how-to-specify-a-format-string-for-an-interpolation-expression) and about string formatting in a string interpolation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0)